Are all these sentences grammatically correct and mean the same thing?

I was a little late to call him.
I was a little late in calling him.
I was a little late for calling him.

Are all three sentences grammatically correct? Do they mean the same thing? The last one, to me, seems to stand out as not being grammatically correct.

These all are grammatically correct, and the first two mean the same thing. The last one is correct, but uncommon and antiquated. In this context, for means because of, which is an old usage that is not heard much anymore. Because of this, the last sentence means "I was late because I called him" implying that the speaker's phone call took a long time and made the speaker late to some other event.
